# How to convert matplot to ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm studying `matplot` and `ggplot2`.

I am facing an issue while trying to convert matplot to ggplot2

```
matplot(iris[,1:4],type="l")

legend("topleft",names(iris)[1:4],lty=c(1,2,3,4),col=c(1,2,3,4))
```

I really can't bring the `Species` part to `ggplot2`.

How can I convert this?

Comment: There is no "Species part" in your matplot.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  select(1:4) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(row, value, color = name) + geom_line()
```

[image]